# chrome extension to control brightness on any website

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, brightness

Is there some good chrome extension that can control the page brightness of all websites?
Something like a brightness slider could be great.. Please help, thanks in adnvance

Comment: Asking for a product recommendation is off-topic here. I also don't understand how this is different than just adjusting the brightness on your monitor.

Comment: @Raystafarian, I agree this one is off topic, but is exactly what I'm looking for. I use dark mode everywhere I can, so switching from an IDE in dark mode to the web in full light mode bleeds the eyes. I just want the browser tinted so that it's not so shocking. Controlling the system brightness is not ideal every time I tab between IDE/browser. There are many other use cases - this is just the most compelling for me. I also use night shift/flux/... on top of it. Without these assistive tools I can't use a computer. I had been using the Dark Reader extension but it's too disruptive.

Comment: @wsams http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to this extension, Sunglasses:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sunglasses/elcjekocfhomlfniihikpmbbgjdbgcoo